# #88 Dynamic Select Menus (revised) doesn't work on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I've a problem with performing (Dynamic select menus on railscast episode) , as it doesn't work properly.

The (State) menu brings all the options available ( Countries+States ).

I've followed the video step by step and searched for available solutions but useless ,but there was a problem that I can't figure it out.

coffescript (people.js.coffee )

```
jQuery ->

states = $('#person_state_id').html()
$('#person_state_id').parent().hide()
$('#person_country_id').change ->
  country = $('#person_country_id :selected').text()
  escaped_country = country.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1')
  options = $(states).filter("optgroup[label='#{escaped_country}']").html()
  console.log(options)
  if options
    $('#person_state_id').html(options).parent().show()
  else
    $('#person_state_id').empty().parent().hide()
```

new.html.erb

## New Person

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
 <div class="field">
 <%= f.label :name %><br />
 <%= f.text_field :name %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :country_id %><br />
  <%= f.collection_select :country_id, Country.order(:name), :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :state_id, "State or Province" %><br />
  <%= f.grouped_collection_select :state_id, Country.order(:name), :states, :name, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
 </div>
 <div class="actions"><%= f.submit %></div>
<% end %>
```

I also found a solution to update the Gemfile with ( gem 'jquery-turbolinks')
and the application.js file with ( //= require jquery.turbolinks ), but useless.

please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the single quotes from this line:

```
options = $(states).filter("optgroup[label='#{escaped_country}']").html()
```

to make it

```
options = $(states).filter("optgroup[label=#{escaped_country}]").html()
```

Comment: Thanks ,but unfortunately, the problem still exist.

Comment: Also, try removing that white line after jQuery ->. Coffee syntax is a bit tricky.

Comment: I removed it but, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Everything is important with Coffee.. White lines are generally not an issue (except rarely)... Indentation is very important though... If you coffee as in your question, or are the lines below it indented?

Comment: After adjusting the indentation http://www10.0zz0.com/2014/02/18/12/741763326.png

Comment: So, there's nothing apparently wrong here. If you're using Firefox or Chrome, try debugging with the console. Perhaps you'll find sthing useful there. (right click->inspect element->console tab)

Answer (score 0):

just try to use this:

`= f.select :country_id, grouped_options_for_select( some_options )`